# Proof that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{4n^3+3n}{n^3-6}=4$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

So I've gotten as far as you see below

$|\frac{4n^3+3n}{n^3-6}-4|<\epsilon$

$|\frac{4n^3 + 3n}{n^3 - 6} - \frac{4n^3 - 24}{n^3 - 6} | < \epsilon$

$|\frac{3n+24}{n^3-6}|<\epsilon$

Assume $n>1$ to drop absolute values.

$\frac{3n+24}{n^3-6}<\epsilon$.

From there, I know we can't solve for $n$ explicitly but I don't quite understand how the estimation is supposed to work.

Also, what do they mean then they say to find an "upper bound for the numerator and a lower bound for the denominator".

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: $\dfrac{\color{blue}4+\dfrac3{n^2}}{1-\dfrac6{n^3}}$

Comment: $|\frac{4n^3+3n}{n^3-6}-4|<\epsilon \Leftrightarrow |\frac{3n+24}{n^3-6}|<\epsilon$ $\Leftarrow \frac{n+8}{n^2}<\frac{\epsilon }{3} 
\Leftarrow \frac{1}{n}+\frac{8}{n^2}<\frac{\epsilon }{3} $

Answer (score 2):

It's not necessary to work out an *exact* formula for the threshold $N$ that $n$ needs to cross in order for the inequality $(3n+24)/n^3\lt\epsilon$ to hold.  Crude estimates can be your friend. Here's one way to go about it:

For *large* $n$ it's clear that

$${3n+24\over n^3}\lt{1\over n}$$

since $3n^2+24n\lt24n^2+24n^2$ for all (positive) $n$ and $48n^2\lt n^3$ if $n\gt48$; indeed with a little extra work we can show $3n^2+24n\lt n^3$ for $n\gt6$. So if $\epsilon$ is *small*, we can take $N=1/\epsilon$ and conclude that $n\gt N$ implies

$${3n+24\over n^3}\lt{1\over n}\lt{1\over N}=\epsilon$$

The only problem is that $\epsilon$ isn't necessarily small; it's arbitrary. So instead we need to take $N=\max\{1/\epsilon,48\}$ (or, if you do the extra work, take $N=\max\{1/\epsilon,6\}$), which now gives us, for $n\gt N$,

$${3n+24\over n^3}\lt n\lt{1\over N}={1\over\max\{1/\epsilon,48\}}=\min\{\epsilon,1/48\}\le\epsilon$$

Comment: Can you say that we're almost treating $\frac{3n+24}{n^3}$ like a "sequence", and to estimate the threshold $N$ such that the initial claim is satisfied, we can find another "sequence" which behaves the similarly that squeezes $\frac{3n+24}{n^3}$ between 0 and this estimate, which is all of course less than $\epsilon$?

Comment: @whitenoise, yes, exactly. That's a nice way to think about it.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for your help. Upvoted! :-]

Answer (score 1):

Let $n>8$;

Then

$n^3-n^2=n^2(n-1)>7n^2>6$; or

$n^3-6 >n^2.$

$f(n):= \dfrac{3(n+8)}{n^3-6} < \dfrac{3(n+n)}{n^2}=$

$6\dfrac{n}{n^2}=6/n$.

$\epsilon >0$ given;

Archimedean principle:

There is a $n_0 >6/\epsilon$.

For $n \ge N:=\max(n_0, 8):$

$f(n)<6/n \le 6/N \le 6/n_0 <\epsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at $\frac{3n+24}{n^3-6}<\epsilon$:

$3n+24=3(n+8)<3(n+n)$ if $n>8$, ie $3n+24<6n$ for $n>8$.

$n^3-6>n^2$ for $n>8$ because $n^3-n^2=n^2(n-1)>7n^2>448>6$

So now we can use these two bounds:
as long as $n>8$, $\frac{3n+24}{n^3-6}<\frac{6n}{n^2}=\frac{6}{n}<\epsilon$ provided $n>\frac{6}{\epsilon}.$

So set $n>\max(8,\frac{6}{\epsilon})$ and you meet the required condition.

Comment: Your statement $n^3-6>n^3\;for\;n>1$ is false.

Comment: @whitenoise - you're right; spectacular fail on my part.  I see another answer has shown $n^3-6>n^2$ for $n>8$ which gets to the answer needed.

Comment: edited my answer to fix that

Comment: Okay, now that makes much more sense. Can you explain why you chose $n>8$?

Comment: I chose $n>8$ to so I could go from $3(n+8)$ to $3(n+n)$ and know that the latter was higher. I've thus found an upper bound for $3n+24$ of $6n$ which only involves $n$ (no constant term) which is easier to work with.  I could have shown $3n+24<4n$ for $n>24$ and worked with $4n$ as upper bound, as long as I have an upper bound that grows at a lower power of $n$ then the lower bound of the denominator.

Comment: So essentially , we're finding a "number' that similar to the one we can't solve for ?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Hope this helps!! Let me know if you have questions or concerns anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Domination Leads To Irrelevancy

$n^3$ dominates $n^2$ as $n\to\infty$, so we can ignore it in the polynomial as we take that limit (in other words, it is irrelevant).

Generally, we have that:
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\bigg[\frac{\sum_{k=0}^m a_k x^k}{\sum_{k=0}^n b_k x^k}\bigg]=\lim_{x\to\infty}\bigg[\frac{a_m}{b_n}x^{m-n}\bigg]$$
holds true for the quotient of any two polynomials $a(x)=\sum_{k=0}^m a_k x^k$ and $b(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n b_k x^k$.

In this case, we see $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigg[\frac{4n^3+3n}{n^3-6}\bigg]=\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigg[\frac41n^{3-3}\bigg]=\lim_{n\to\infty}4=4$$